# How to test a code requiring user input within lambda function in JAVA 8?

Tags: java, java-8

Lambdas are great, i love them, but i am working with the following code, This code is giving me grieve, it makes the code impossible to unit test. The code is requesting a UI object and using that object to handle some user input, then again runs its own code thats is requesting more user input:
*(please remember that the actual code is not really asking for confirmation, so it is not redundant, it is actually asking for input to be passed to a choice of a few function calls, i just simplified it so i don't have to provide the entire code here)*

. How would you handle unit testing with all these user inputs? what is an alternative way to handle user inputs within a lambda?

---

`GreenPlayerCard.java`:

```
public void cardOne((player, game) -> {
            TextUserInterface UI = TextUserInterface.getUI();

            Set<GreenPlayerCard> playerCards = player.getPlayerCards();

            discardCard = UI.getCardChoice(playerCards,"Choose a card to discard: ");

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String optionChoice = null;
            System.out.println("\t1- to Confirm Discard Card, enter 1");
            System.out.println("\t2- Do nothing, enter 2");
            System.out.print("Choice: ");
            optionChoice = scanner.nextLine();
        
            switch (optionChoice){
            case "1":
            {
                game.discardCard(discardCard, player);
                break;
            }           
            case "2":
                break;
                
            default: System.out.println("\tPlease enter your choice:");
            }
                break;
            }
})
```

---

`TextUserInterface.java` (this is a singleton):

```
public <C extends Card> C getCardChoice(Collection<C> cards, String message) {
    Map<Integer, C> cardMap = new HashMap<>();
    System.out.println(message);
    int i = 1;
    for (C c : cards) {
        System.out.print(i + ") ");
        System.out.println(c);
        cardMap.put(i, c);
        i++;
    }
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true) {
        try {
            int action = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
            if(cardMap.get(action) == null) {
                System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
                continue;
            }
            return cardMap.get(action); 
        } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number.");
            scanner.next();
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code isn’t valid Java and it’s not clear what it is supposed to be. It looks like `cardOne` is supposed to be a method while it is mangled with a lambda expression at the same time. Maybe you get your own answer once you made correct Java code out of this fragement…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question which doesn’t have anything to do with lambda expressions. It’s about software design. In your code, a piece of code implementing program logic (which happens to be a lambda expression) has a hardwired creation of `new Scanner(System.in)` in it.

The problems with that are not connected to the fact that the code is a lambda expression and neither does the solution depend on it. You have to provide the `Scanner` from the surrounding context. Generally, you would have to abstract user interfaces to make testing possible. If you have an `interface` which can be implemented by either, actually asking the user or providing a predefined value from the testcase, you can test any code which works on an instance of that `interface`.

In case of a `Scanner` it is a bit easier as it already is an abstraction. You may simply create a `Scanner` instance operating on predefined input, e.g. via `StringReader` to enable testing of code working with a `Scanner`. The only requirement is that the code using the `Scanner` doesn’t create its own `Scanner` instance in a hardwired way but uses an instance provided from the surrounding context instead.

At this point you may consider putting the code into a named method as it’s pretty big for a lambda expression anyway. Maybe that’s what you already attempted with the invalid code fragment of your question:

```
public void cardOne(Scanner scanner, PlayerType player, GameType game) {
    TextUserInterface UI = TextUserInterface.getUI();
    Set<GreenPlayerCard> playerCards = player.getPlayerCards();
    discardCard = UI.getCardChoice(playerCards,"Choose a card to discard: ");

    String optionChoice = null;
    System.out.println("\t1- to Confirm Discard Card, enter 1");
    System.out.println("\t2- Do nothing, enter 2");
    System.out.print("Choice: ");
    input: for(;;) {
        optionChoice = scanner.nextLine();
        switch (optionChoice) {
        case "1":
            game.discardCard(discardCard, player);
            break input;
        case "2": break input;
        default: System.out.println("\tPlease enter your choice:");
        }
    }
}
```

If you have that method, you can test it easily by passing a prepared `Scanner` instance. Within the actual application you can use it with a lambda expression which may look like

```
(player, game) -> handleCardOne(new Scanner(System.in), player, game)
```

but you may consider calling `new Scanner(System.in)` at the beginning of the application and keeping that one instance.

The actual lambda expression follows the rule of thump that lambda expression should be short enough to be “too simple to fail” thus not require its own test case. Every time a lambda expression becomes so complex that you have doubts about it, you should consider moving the code into a named, testable method.